# Open ITunes software from a ASP.NET application

Tags: .net, asp.net, itunes, ipod

I have a MP3 file on the server and want to make it easy for a user to add this to their ITunes library on a click of a button, so that they can add it to their Ipod.

Is this requirement reasonable and possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of executable program on the user's computer (most likely a Browser Helper Object (BHO)), which means requiring a software installation.  It might be a one-click installation, but it's still an installation.

You can't do it in the browser sandbox because you don't have sufficient rights to the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access applications like this from the browser, unfortunately. However, most people with iPods who use iTunes to manage them probably have iTunes set as their default application for MP3 files. The clearest way may simply be to provide a link to the file with brief instructions (right-click, save as, open in iTunes).